# Google datastore: insert entity to another database

Tags: c#, google-cloud-datastore

Google datastore allow users to create multiple databases. The default one is `(default)`, while custom created databases may have other names.

If I want to insert an entity to the `(default)` database, I'm using this code (c#):

```
Entity task = new Entity()
{
    Key = _keyFactory.CreateIncompleteKey()
};
task.Key = _db.Insert(task);
```

[(source)](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/samples/datastore-insert)

Assuming I created another database called `tests`, how I can insert the entity to this database (instead of `(default)`)?

Comment: We don't currently support multiple databases in Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1, although you could use `_db.Client` to get the "raw" gRPC client and run the requests yourself if you absolutely had to. I'm not going to promise any dates, but I expect we *will* implement multi-database support at some point in the not *too* distant future.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing this as a community wiki for the benefit of others

As mentioned by @Jon Skeet

> We don't currently support multiple databases in Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1, although you could use _db.Client to get the "raw" gRPC client and run the requests yourself if you absolutely had to. I'm not going to promise any dates, but I expect we will implement multi-database support at some point in the not too distant future.