# How do I change the GCP Datastore database connection in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to change the database within GCP Datastore I am connected to in my node app.

I have got the connection and auth up and running, with my app being deployed using Cloud Run. I am able to connect to the default database using `const datastore = new Datastore();`.

However I am not able to change to a named database within the GCP project. I have tried a number of different options but the documentation is lacking. The only thing I can find online about accessing named databases is [this small paragraph from the Google Documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-databases?&_ga=2.202028049.-1679016822.1671112771&_gac=1.259678840.1696002254.CjwKCAjw69moBhBgEiwAUFCx2BFAkJsnmTeEK234f9hfHHleGQpvdxnJMWMXoQT2hedxDnRQ79eSvRoCjkQQAvD_BwE#access_a_named_database_with_a_client_library)

Below is my entire test file:

```
const { Datastore } = require("@google-cloud/datastore");

const datastore = new Datastore();

export const testFunction = async (
    postBody: any,
) => {
  try {
      quickstart(postBody);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Error executing workflow: ${e}`);
  }
}

async function quickstart(postBody: any) {

    const { test, name } = postBody;
    
    // The kind for the new entity
    const kind = 'hello';

    // The Cloud Datastore key for the new entity
    const taskKey = datastore.key([kind, test]);
  
    // Prepares the new entity
    const task = {
      key: taskKey,
      data: {
          name : name 
      },
    };
  
    // Saves the entity
    await datastore.save(task);
    console.log(`Saved ${task.key.test}: ${task.data.name }`);
  }
export default { testFunction };
```

I have attempted some of the following with no luck:

- `const datastore = new Datastore("test-database");`
- `const datastore = new Datastore({ databaseId: "test-database", });`
- `const datastore = new Datastore({ namespace: "test-database", });`

Comment: What error do you get? Do you have the latest version of the datastore client library (remember that named databases are new and are still in 'preview' mode). Note that since you're dealing with datastore, [this](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/manage-databases) is the documentation you should be looking at and not the one you linked to

Comment: @NoCommandLine I am not receiving any error - my app is running on Cloud Run. I am able to post data to it, and it is storing in the (default) database instead of a named database. I do have the latest version of the client library.

I took a look at the documentation you linked to, and it contains the same (word for word) documentation on connecting to a named database. Again, the documentation Google provides isn't the most useful, and I am still left with the same problem.

Comment: How did you create the named database?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I created the database using the gcloud commands found in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/manage-databases#create_a_database). The database exists, and can be seen both on the GUI and using the `gcloud firestore databases list` command.

Comment: I tested on local machine using datastore emulator and sample code from [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/main/test/query.ts#L565C5-L569C7) and it also went to the default database. You should raise an issue with Google (on GitHub)

Comment: Actually, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77142687/google-datastore-insert-entity-to-another-database) from a Google Employee

Answer (score 1):

Support for named databases in the Node.js client library was released today (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/releases/tag/v8.2.0). `const datastore = new Datastore({ databaseId: "test-database", });` should work with v8.2.0 .